# Terrell rotation with doppler shift on relativistic dice

Tags: special-relativity, relativity, doppler-effect

Imagine a spaceship flew past Earth and at that moment it threw out a standard 6 sided dice and my ground based telescope managed to capture the atmospheric entry of the relativistic dice, I wonder how many sides of the dice can I see at any given instant and would one side be more blue shifted than the others?

Comment: You will see exactly as many sides as you would see when stationary.  Terrell "rotation" just "throws" a side-on view forwards owing to optical aberration effects on your field of view.

Comment: @m4r35n357: can you expand into an answer and do you mean length contraction is not contraction and Terrell's rotation is not rotation.

Comment: I make no statement about length contraction here!  The effect I am referring to is called "relativistic beaming".  It makes things that are alongside you appear to be in front of you.  In other words, the plane that divides what is in front of you from that behind you is "thrown forwards" into a cone.  This distortion makes visible things that would otherwise be outside your field of view, but because they appear in front of you the perspective becomes unfamiliar to the eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK as requested I am going to attempt an answer, for better or worse!

I have made some videos [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLvGnzGhIWTGR-O332xj0sToA0Yk1X7IuI) that illustrate this distortion, but they might be a little "busy" for this discussion.  Please read the description in the left panel, it appears to be brief but contains a lot of information.

If you [watch the goalposts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0HGGYfcyqI&list=PLvGnzGhIWTGR-O332xj0sToA0Yk1X7IuI&index=3&t=0s) as the ship returns to its starting point (past the half way point), you see the underside/inside edges "bulging" out in front of you.  When you can only see the underside/inside surfaces of the posts, you are actually level with them, even though they appear in front of you!  At this point the posts form a circle.  Further on, you can see the "far side" edges in front of you.  In fact you have already passed the posts, but again aberration has distorted the view so that the back appears in front of you.

I hope you are now able to translate this discussion to dice strewn along the route.